# Implement an emedder for rnnDataset which takes an input tensor, transforms it to words->tokens->embeddings, then stores the embeddings

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

I need to write a function to embed an RNN dataset that takes the inputs as tensors and transforms them to words. I know the function has the structure below but don't know how to declare the arguments.

```
def rnn_embedder(tensor, embedding_length):
'''
# Takes a tensor and a vocabulary and returns the BoW embedding of that tensor
# Args:
    tensor (torch.Tensor): A tensor of words represented by their index in the vocabulary
    vocab_lenght (int): The number of entries in the vocabulary
Returns (torch.Tensor): An tensor containing the BoW embedding of the input tensor
'''

tensor = tensor.long()
embedding = ...
words = ...

for ...

return numpy.asarray(embedding)
```